# What is the mechanism of private key for decryption in PKCS11

Tags: encryption, rsa, private-key, pkcs#11

Here is some part of my code

I already encrypt some text from another app VB.net via RSACryptoProvider

But I stuck at the step to decrypt in C.

Here is my code.

```
static CK_RV usePrivateKeytoDecrypt(CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession, CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hObject) {
CK_RV rv = CKR_OK;
CK_MECHANISM mechanism = {
    {CKM_RSA_PKCS_OAEP}
};

rv = C_DecryptInit(hSession, &mechanism, hObject);

return rv;
```

}

The code is not completed. I try to debug and got the error CKR_MECHANISM_PARAM_INVALID

Please help. Thanks

Comment: The error message is saying exactly as its name suggests: the parameter (i.e. hObject) is invalid. How so, we have no idea because you provided no information about that.

Comment: A cursory check shows that you didn't set mechanism's `pParameter` and `ulParameterLen` values to represent [CK_RSA_PKCS_OAEP_PARAMS](https://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v220/structCK__RSA__PKCS__OAEP__PARAMS.html). OAEP has options, which are encoded in that structure.

Comment: I have same problem. So what is correct parameters setting for CKM_RSA_PKCS_OAEP ? I got same error when use CK_MECHANISM MechEncrypt = { CKM_RSA_PKCS_OAEP, NULL_PTR, 0};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correctly initializing your mechanism structure. The CK_MECHANISM is a structure that requires 3 parameters to be defined:

```
typedef struct CK_MECHANISM {
  CK_MECHANISM_TYPE mechanism;
  CK_VOID_PTR       pParameter;
  CK_ULONG          ulParameterLen;  /* in bytes */
} CK_MECHANISM;
```

You need to initialize your mechanism as follow:

```
CK_MECHANISM  mechanism = { CKM_RSA_PKCS_OAEP, NULL_PTR, 0 };
```

If you generated your private-public key-pair as RSA key-pair (using CKM_RSA_PKCS_KEY_PAIR_GEN mechanism) e.g.

```
CK_MECHANISM  GenMechanism = { CKM_RSA_PKCS_KEY_PAIR_GEN, NULL_PTR, 0 };
```

Then you need to initialize your mechanism for decryption as follow:

```
CK_MECHANISM  mechanism   = { CKM_RSA_PKCS, NULL_PTR, 0};
```

I presume you are already logged in with your hsession and the hObject is the located private key to be used for decryption?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the algorithm of the Key Pair.

If the Key Pair's algorithm is **RSA**, it could be **CKM_RSA_PKCS** / **CKM_RSA_PKCS_OAEP** / **CKM_RSA_X_509**.

If the Key Pair's algorithm is **EC**, it could be **CKM_ECDSA**.

Provided, the Private Key has the attribute **CKA_DECRYPT** set to true.

You can refer to this [documentation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-curr/v2.40/csprd02/pkcs11-curr-v2.40-csprd02.html) here.

Answer (score 1):

You must set mechanism parameters:

```
CK_RSA_PKCS_OAEP_PARAMS oaepParams = {CKM_SHA_1, CKG_MGF1_SHA1, 1, NULL_PTR, 0};
CK_MECHANISM MechEncrypt = {CKM_RSA_PKCS_OAEP, &oaepParams, sizeof(oaepParams)};
```